# Find the equation of a line normal to a given function, given its slope (no points.)

Tags: calculus, derivatives, conic-sections, tangent-line

I have no idea how to solve this without points.

Find the equation of the line, normal to $y=(2-x)^4$, which has slope equal to $-\dfrac{1}{32}$

If it helps, the solution is $y=(-1/32)x+(129/8)$

But I truly have no idea how to solve this.

Comment: The slope  of the normal line is just the negative of the reciprocal of the slope of the tangent,  and the latter is the value of the derivative.  So find the derivative, equate it to the  slope of the tangent and solve for x, then solve for y, then you will have a point and the given slope, from which you can find the equation of the normal.

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea I did do exactly what you said, but it does not equal to that answer.. which is why I came on to ask

Comment: @Calmdownandhavesometea No, you would have to equate the derivative to the *negative reciprocal* of the slope given. I am writing a full answer right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y=(-x+2)^4$

$y'= 4(-x+2)^3(-1)$ [By Product Rule]

$y'=-4(2-x)^3$

$y' = 32$ due to being the negative reciprocal of the slope of the normal line

$32=-4(2-x)^3$

$x=4$

$y=16$

$y-y_1 = m(x-x_1)$

$y-16 = -(1/32)(x-4)$

$y=-(1/32)x+(129/8)$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

The slope of the normal is given as $- \dfrac{1}{32} $, therefore, the slope of the tangent line is $32$

Now, the derivative is $ y' = 4 (x - 2)^3 $

Equate this expression to $32$ you get

$(x - 2)^3 = 8 $

Hence $x = 4$, and from this, $y = (2)^4 = 16 $

Now we have the point $(4, 16)$ and the slope of the normal line,

so its equation is

$ y  - 16 = - \frac{1}{32} (x - 4 ) $

Which becomes

$ y = - \dfrac{1}{32} x + 16 + 1/8 = - \dfrac{1}{32} x + \dfrac{129}{8} $

Comment: Thank you so muchhh! 

Oh I did something really wrong on the finding the x part, for some reason I directly cubed the things in the brackets, hahaha.....